# Calling next script on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to open about.py when 'about' link is pressed from the file menu of the main.py. Once again I apologize for asking the kid question. Thanks in advance.

suppose this is main.py:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import about

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("File dialog")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)

        fileMenu.add_command(label="About", command=self.onAbout)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)        

        self.txt = Text(self)
        self.txt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)



    def onAbout(self):
        pass #how can I call about.py here..?



def main():

    root = Tk()
    ex = Example(root)
    root.geometry("300x250+300+300")
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And about.py look some thing like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

class About(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        pass


def main():

    root = Tk()
    ex = About(root)
    root.geometry("630x400+200+200")
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
def onAbout(self):
    new_root = Tk()
    new_root.geometry("630x400+200+200")
    About(root)
```

Comment: you can't do that. You are always creating either a new dialog or window. And in a way you are calling the new file, because you import it.

Comment: Ok I got you. Thanks..!!